# krajee bootstrap file input ajax ashyncronous not passing uploadExtraData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using file-input bootstrap using [Krajee](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input-ajax-demo/7).

This is my code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
   <input type="text" id="value_search" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan No IR">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" type="button" id="search">Search!</button>
       </span>
 </div>
```

My storyboard is like this. With code above, people can input a number into a text input. Then with a button, people send it into my js code.
Just say it will be a document number like `00001`.

Now time to fileinput :

```
<label for="file">Upload Foto</label>
<input name="exterior[]" id="exterior" class="file-loading" type="file" multiple>
```

This is my js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var search;
    $('#search').click(function () {
        search = $('#value_search').val();
        if (search !== "") {
            alert("Anda tidak mengisi kata kunci");
        }
    });

    $("#exterior").fileinput({
        uploadUrl: "c_admin_ir/add_file_image/exterior/", // server upload action
        uploadAsync: true,
        maxFileCount: 5,
        uploadExtraData: {
            nomor: String(search)
        }

    });
 });
```

I have two troubles. 
I debug it on my PHP CODE like this :

```
public function add_file_image($tipe){
    print_r($_FILES['exterior']);
    echo $_POST['number'];
}
```

For `print_r($_FILES['exterior']);`
Lets say i uploaded two files, And I see the uploadUrl running twice on firebug. Is it multiple upload ? or just a single upload working at two times ?

And for `echo $_POST['number'];`
It gives me "undefined" in firebug. It was not `00001`

For help, sharing, or suggestion, it so appreciated.
Thanks.